# prevent users from seeing full path

Tags: url, hyperlink

I want to know if there is a way to prevent visitors on the website to see the full site url .. so for example instead of http://www.5eren.dk/index.php all the user see's is http://www.5eren.dk .. is this possible ?

Comment: Check out .htaccess or mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding you correctly check out .htaccess rewrite condition and rewrite engine.
For example to hide a file extension:

```
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This should get you started.

Answer (score -1):

**Simply NO**

However, depending on your [server-side](/questions/tagged/server-side) scripting technology you use on your website, such functionality may be applied by a mean of central script that call some URL on your website and render it as it is being the requested script with some param.

For example:

Suppose the following URL

http://myexample.com/secrets/pages/output.php

Now we may request it using some routing script as follows:

http://myexample.com/routing.php?routeID=123

Using some database inside your routing script you may able to call or include the secrets/pages/ouput.php